# Why does Python often separate the exception type and value (exc_info, __exit__, etc)?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

[`traceback.format_exception_only`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception_only) has arguments `(etype, value)`. If I have an exception `e` that I want to format, in what situation would I not want to call `format_exception_only(type(e), e)`?

`sys.exc_info` returns a type, value, and traceback. The `__exit__` method of a context manager has the same three things as parameters. Is the type not redundant? Can it be equal to something other than `type(value)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historical reasons.

Way back in the 1.x days, this information wasn't all bundled up in a single object. The exception type was a **string(!)** rather than a class, the value was some arbitrary object, and the traceback wasn't attached to either of those objects. All the `type, value, traceback` APIs were built around this design, where these objects had to be passed around separately:

```
MyException = "MyException"

raise MyException, 3
```

Some time in the 1.x line ([I think 1.2](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8bf7c484c16edfc5084732fdd6d8b64a0f921930)), they added class-based exceptions, and some time in the 2.x line (I think 2.6, since the [2.5 branch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.5/Python/ceval.c#L3105) code path seems to only raise a warning), string exceptions were removed, but the old function signatures stuck around.

Comment: "the traceback wasn't attached to either of those objects" isn't that still the case?

Comment: @AlexHall: In Python 3, the traceback is available as the `__traceback__` attribute of the exception object.

Comment: Huh, didn't realise that. The python 2 docs warn that the cycle created by storing the traceback is inefficient. Does the new attribute hurt efficiency in Python 3 or is it magic?

Comment: @AlexHall: As specified in [PEP 3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/), Python 3 will automatically `del` the `except` target to break the cycle when control leaves the `except` block.

Answer (score 4):

Python used to allow string objects as exceptions back in 1.x days. Strings don't have arguments, unlike `Exception` instances.

String exceptions were deprecated in 1.5, and removed in <s>2.0</s> 2.6. Since then, it's just backwards compatibility, I suppose. It's not a problem enough to command a breaking change.

Comment: Python 3 was supposed to be the time for breaking changes.

Comment: @MarkRansom: For _some_ breaking changes, not "break all the things" changes. It broke enough things to have a very slow acceptance curve even without that. The low-level API for traceback access is rarely used, mostly by developers of  frameworks, debuggers, profilers, etc. Breaking it would leave nascent Python 3 without these, potentially very important, tools for some time; without a _damn_ good reason it probably wasn't worth doing.

Comment: 2.0 still had string exceptions. I think they were only fully removed in 2.6; the [2.5 branch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.5/Python/ceval.c#L3105) still has the handling for them in the `raise` implementation, with a `DeprecationWarning`.